# Why is my floor not flat to the ground?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I want it to be at 0 on the y-axis, that is what I mean by flat to the ground.

I am making the floor of my game in android, I am using opengl es 1. I have a square I am using as the floor, so obviously I want it to be flat to the ground. I want the y-axis to be 0, but whenever I set it to this the square isn't on the screen. But if I set all of the y-axis to 0.1 then the square is hovering from the center of the screen to the top right corner, not flat to the ground.

This is the vertices array:

```
float w = 10;
float h = 10;
float vertices[] ={
    0f, 0.1f, 0f,
    w, 0.1f, 0f,
    0f, 0.1f, -h,
    w,  0.1f, -h
};
```

I am then storing it in the normal float buffer:

```
ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mFVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    mFVertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    mFVertexBuffer.position(0);
```

And then when it comes to drawing it:

```
gl.glDrawElements( GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,2*3, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mIndexBuffer);
```

And this is setting up the frustum, which I don't think should make a difference but...

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float aspectRatio;
    float zNear =.1f;
    float zFar = 1000f;
    float fieldOfView = 1f;
    float size;
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_NORMALIZE);
    aspectRatio=(float)width/(float)height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    size = zNear * (float)(Math.tan((double)(fieldOfView/2.0f)));
    gl.glFrustumf(-size, size, -size /aspectRatio, 
            size /aspectRatio, zNear, zFar);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Why is it not flat? and why when the y-axis is 0, does it disappear?
I am tring to achieve this: 
[image]

Where the white section is the floor.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be a lot more descriptive. What does 'flat to the ground' even mean in an arbitrary 3d orientation? What projection and view matrices are you using?

Comment: There we go I tried to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Well I gave a desciption of flat to the ground, didn't I? And you don't really use view matricies in es 1 do you?

Comment: The concept of view matrix is certainly applicable to OpenGLES 1, though it's just combined with the model matrix (the "ModelView" matrix). It's not a requirement that you use it, though it makes things conceptually much easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is "disappearing", because your object has no height.

It's like if you were holding an infinitely thin piece of paper flat in front of your eyes. If the paper is above or below your field of vision, then you can see it, but if you put it exactly parallel to your eyes, you wouldn't be able to see it.

It's not really clear to me what you expect it to look like. How do you  want this floor to look, will you be looking at it from above, or from an angle? Do you want it to fill from the center of the screen to the bottom? Maybe a mockup image could really help explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you want to draw your floor at y=0, and if you want the camera to be above the floor, then you want to set the view matrix to represent a camera with a height higher than y=0. One way to achieve this is to use gluLookAt. @Aaron